# Electrical across studs in basement?

Tags: electrical, studs

I have a small workshop that I need to add an outlet for. There's a light switch 2 studs away that I'll use for power.

I have no plans to drywall this area of the workshop.

Is it ok (against any kind of code) to run romex across studs (instead of boring through)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are codes against running nonmetallic sheathed cable (Type NM) along the edge of studs. The cable must be protected from physical damage (NEC 300.4), which it would not be on the edge of the studs.

If you don't want to bore holes, you can use schedule 80 PVC conduit (or any conduit rated to protect cable).

Even if you do bore holes. Since you're not covering the wall, the cable could still be considered "exposed".  In which case, it would need to be protected from physical damage.